# BSON Decoder exception

Tags: mongodb, bson

Since Mongo uses BSON, I am using the BSONDecoder from Java API to get the BSON document from the Mongo query and print the string output. In the following a byte[] array stores the bytes of the MongoDB document (when I print the hex values they are the same as in Wireshark)

```
  byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();
  BasicBSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
  BSONObject bsonObject = decoder.readObject(array);
  System.out.println(bsonObject.toString());
```

I get the following error:

```
  org.bson.BSONException: should be impossible
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected EOF
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder$BSONInput._need(BasicBSONDecoder.java:327)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder$BSONInput.read(BasicBSONDecoder.java:364)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:118)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:79)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:57)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.readObject(BasicBSONDecoder.java:42)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.readObject(BasicBSONDecoder.java:32)
    ... 4 more

Looking on the implementation 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/LazyBSONDecoder.java it looks that it is caught in

```
        throw new BSONException( "should be impossible" , ioe );
```

The above takes place in query to the database (by query I mean that byte[] array contains all the bytes after the document length). The query itself contains a string "ismaster" or in hex is "x10 ismaster x00 x01 x00 x00 x00 x00". I suspect it is the BSON format of {isMaster: 1}, but I still do not understand why it fails.

Comment: what version of driver and mongodb is this?

Comment: I am calling the mongo-2.8.0.jar in the classpath, and I have installed the 2.0.4-1ubuntu2 from Synaptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
byte[] array = new BigInteger("130000001069734d6173746572000100000000", 16).toByteArray();
BasicBSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
BSONObject bsonObject = decoder.readObject(array);
System.out.println(bsonObject.toString());
```

And produces this output:

> { "isMaster" : 1}

There is something wrong with the bytes in your byteBuffer. Note that you *must* include the whole document (including the first 4 bytes which are the size).

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> byte[] array contains all the bytes after the document length

If you are stripping off the first part of the BSON that's returned, you are not passing a valid BSON document to the parser/decoder.

See [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) for details, but in a nut-shell, the first four bytes are the total size of the binary document in little endian format.

You are getting an exception in [the code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/BasicBSONDecoder.java#L358) that is basically trying to read an expected number of bytes.  It read the first int32 as length and then tried to parse the rest of it as BSON elements (and got an exception when it didn't find a valid type in the next byte).  Pass it everything you get back from the query, including document size and it will work correctly.

Comment: Actually, I have tried w/ and w/o the document length and it does not seem to work. In fact, I do not understand why it is not caught in "line 83 -> throw new IllegalArgumentException( "bad data. lengths don't match read:" + _in.numRead() + " != len:" + len );" when I exclude the document length. In any case, your post is helpful as it excludes one possibility from my trials.

Comment: could you post the bson that you are trying to decode (with length) and the full stack trace when you include the length?

Comment: This is the BSON document as it appears in Wireshark: 13 00 00 00 10 69 73 6d 61 73 74 65 72 00 01 00 00 00 00. 13 00 00 00 is the document length = 19 and the rest is probably {isMaster: 1}. You can generate the same message through a db.open.

Comment: ha resolved it! The BSONDecoder uses the byte[] array length to determine the EOF. This must be equal to the document length.

Comment: The size of the array doesn't matter, you can include extra bytes. You must have all the bytes given the size of the document (first 4 bytes in the header).